# I want to use "data:image/jpeg;base64" as an image tweet in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, base64, twitter-oauth, imagick

I want to use "data:image/jpeg;base64" as an image tweet in PHP.

Current code

```
$originImg = "/var/www/a.jpg";

function testFunc($param){
  $im = new Imagick($param);
  $result = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($im->current());
  $im->destroy();
  return $result;
}

$testFuncReturn = testFunc($originImg);

require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
$mediaId = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $testFuncReturn]);
$mediaIdString = $mediaIdAry->media_id_string;
$parameters = [
  'status' => 'hogetext',
  'media_ids' => implode(',', $mediaIdString)
];

$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
if( $connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200 ){
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "fail";
}
```

What I have tried

```
// $result = base64_encode($im->current());
// $result = $im->current();
// $result = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $im->current();
// $result = mime_content_type('data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($im->current()));

// $resultAry[0] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($im->current());
// $resultAry[1] = mime_content_type('data:;base64,' . base64_encode($im->current()));
// $mediaId = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $resultAry[0], 'media_type' => $resultAry[1]], true);
```

Error message

> InvalidArgumentException: You must supply a readable file
>
> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for
> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA
>
> Warning: mime_content_type(/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA

PHP Version

> PHP 7.2.3

Twitter API

> 1.1

Comment: The error is not coming from PHP, or the Twitter API, it's from the library you're using: it is expecting a local filename, and you're giving it a URL. Look at the documentation for the library, find an alternative library, or roll your own function.

Comment: I don't know what `$im->current()` returns but you might want to surround this with a `file_get_contents`. `base64_encode()` [requires a `string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)